# html5 validation as an automatic test in Java

Tags: java, html, validation, testing

I want to create a html5-validator that catches the obsolete tags and doesn't allow tags/attributes that are not currently mentioned in the working draft of html5.

I have looked into validator.nu, but I am not able to get it to fail on unknown tags/attributes. I have also tried using xerces and schema-validation with a html5-schema, but this doesn't work as well as I want to.

So, my question is, have anyone created a piece of java-code that does html5-validation? Can I please have a look at it :-)

Comment: Did you have a look at [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't support html5